# I am using WordPress to build a site (slug and permalink issue)

Tags: wordpress, post, permalinks, slug

when I go to the single.php file and pull in the content for a post using get_the_content(); it always pulls in the first post from the eventsE custom posts (and yet the slug appears to be that of the post it's supposed to show). Every post title I click on shows the first post in the custom posts and yet the slug is always for the actual post it's supposed to show. I have made different content for each post in the WordPress admin panel and the get_the_content(); function should be pulling that content, and not just always returning the first post through the permalinks. Does anybody have any idea of what might be going wrong? Thank you.
Single.php:

```
<?php $lang = substr(get_locale(), 0, 2) ?>
<html lang="<? echo $lang ?>">
<?php

get_header(); ?>
<div class="section2">
</div>
<?php if ($lang == "en") : ?>
<?php
$homepageEventsE = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => 'eventEnglish',
'category__in' => array(6),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));

while ($homepageEventsE->have_posts() && ($lang == "en") ):
$homepageEventsE->the_post(); 
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
  
if( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ):
comments_template();

endif;

endwhile;

?>
    
<?php 
elseif ($lang == "fr") : ?>
<?php
$homepageEventsF = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => 'evenementFrancais',
'category__in' => array(5),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
while ($homepageEventsF->have_posts() && ($lang == "fr") ) :
$homepageEventsF->the_post(); 
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single2' );
  
if( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ):
comments_template();

endif;

endwhile;

endif; ?>
<?php
get_footer(); ?>
```

content-single.php:

```
<div id="primary">
<div id="main">
<a class="speciala" href="#"><img src="<?php echo 
get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/calendar.png" alt="date icon">
<?php $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date')); echo 
$eventDate->format('M') ?>
<?php echo $eventDate->format('d') ?></a>
<a class="specx" href="<?php echo site_url('/events'); ?>">Events 
Home</a>
<div class="sqbox2"><?php the_title(); ?><br /><br /><?php echo 
get_the_content();  ?><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('/events'); ?> 
">View All Events</a></p>
</div></div></div>
```

archive.php

```
<?php $lang = substr(get_locale(), 0, 2) ?>
<html lang="<? echo $lang ?>">

<?php
get_header(); ?>
<br />
<br />
<?php if ($lang == "en") : ?>
<h1>WICG Events</h1>
<br />
<?php
$today = date('Ymd');
$homepageEventsE = new WP_Query(array(
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
'post_type' => 'eventEnglish',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'category__in' => array(6),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
if ($homepageEventsE->have_posts()) :
while ($homepageEventsE->have_posts() && ($lang == "en")) {
$homepageEventsE->the_post(); 

get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive' );

}  
wp_reset_postdata();
echo paginate_links();
endif;
?>

<hr class="section-break">
<p>Click on the post titles to see the single post and leave comments on 
it if you wish.</p>
<br/>
<p>Looking for a recap of past events?<a href="<?php echo 
site_url('/past-events') ?>"> Check out our past events archive.</a></p>

?>

<?php elseif ($lang == "fr") : ?>
<h1>Événements GCOI</h1>
<br />
<?php
$today = date('Ymd');
$homepageEventsF = new WP_Query(array(
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
'post_type' => 'evenementFrancais',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'category__in' => array(5),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
if ($homepageEventsF->have_posts()) :
while ($homepageEventsF->have_posts() && ($lang == "fr")) {
$homepageEventsF->the_post(); 

get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive2' );
}    
wp_reset_postdata();  
echo paginate_links();
endif;
?>

<hr class="section-break">
<p>Cliquez sur les titres des publications pour voir la publication 
unique et laissez des commentaires si vous le souhaitez.</p>
<br/>
<p>Voulez voir un sommaire de les événements passé de GCOI?<a href="<? 
php echo site_url('/fr/past-events') ?>"> Regarder notre archiver des 
événements passé.</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer();

?>
```

content-archive.php

```
<a class="speciala" href="#"><img src="<?php echo 
get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/calendar.png" alt="date icon">
<?php $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
echo $eventDate->format('M') ?>

<?php echo $eventDate->format('d') ?></a>
<div class="sqbox2">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-label="Archives post title"><? 
php the_title(); ?></a><br /><br />
<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

The permalink from content-archive.php is supposed to link to each separate single post, but it only brings up the first post in either English or French from the custom posts with each permalink.

Comment: could you share the codes of the single.php file?

Comment: Ok, I updated my post.